# ELK / Lucene - select events by absence of another event

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, aws-lambda, elastic-stack

I have a Lambda function in AWS which reports logs to an ELK instance.
Each invocation of the lambda function generates a unique `invocation_id` that is sent with every log event, so the events from a single invocation can be identified in ELK.
At the end of the operation, I send a "Done" event.

A Lambda function can fail, or timeout, and then the "Done" event is not sent.

I want to create a query to show all the invocations that don't have a "Done" event. An SQL parallel could be:

```
select invocation_id
from events
where invocation_id not in (select invocation_id
                            from events
                            where event_type = 'Done'
                            group by invocation_id)
group by invocation_id
```

I know there are no "subqueries" in ElasticSearch, but maybe there is some other way to do that?

---

**EDIT:**

I am trying a different approach, please look here: [Logstash Filter: aggregate - auto save on timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603086/logstash-filter-aggregate-auto-save-on-timeout)

Comment: I think you need to use two queries for this.

Comment: Can you provide some information about your index structure?

Comment: @MichaelStockerl I have no explicit index definitions, I am using an external ELK SaaS and just throw all my logs in there. They are supposed to handle the indexing themselves as part of the service.
Is there something I can do with an index definition to solve my problem?

Comment: Ah, I might have a solution for a parent / child index, but I think you won't have your index like that... Sorry :(